Book about parallel universes, but tv connects them?
I’ve been searching for this book for years, but I’ve never been able to find it because I only remember random bits and pieces of it. I’ll try to list the things I think I remember.

As stated in the title, I want to say the parallel universes, in the end, were connected through a television. There was some note that passed through, and that’s how the characters communicated/became aware of the others’ existence.
In the parallel universe, I believe there was some kind of really extreme acid rain.
Also in the parallel universe, I believe the main character was a guy. In the main world, the main character was a girl. I think the guy dislocated his elbow/shoulder at one point, playing some sport.
Toward the beginning, one of the characters mentions stuff about peoples auras. I want to say it was the main character’s mother…
They also mentioned one character’s mole a lot. I believe it was the main character’s best friend (I don’t know, I’m just trying to throw out every detail I can possibly remember)
The cover had a woman on it. She was holding something, I believe, like an umbrella, or a balloon. That, or she was stepping into a puddle.

This is all I really remember. It’s been somewhere around 10 years since I read this book, if I had to guess. I could tell you the exact location I grabbed it from in my elementary school library, but nothing else about the book :/
